# Why media queries not working with some classes in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, media-queries

I've started previously working with bootstrap (still in V.3.7) and I have a case in that I'm working with something like facebook cover image and profile image for my laptop screen all is well but when I shrink the screen I notice the my media queries are not working but the previous media queries are working with no problems .. I'll post my media queries bellow if there is any problem with them I'll be glade if any one correct them:

```
/* Small devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
    .header .navbar-default{
        background-color: #fff !important;
        border-color: #e6e6e6;
    }
    .about-iphone img{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .signup .col-md-3{
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    .modal-dialog {
        margin: 30px auto;
        width: 350px;
    }
    .modal-content {
        width: 350px;
    }
    #modal-img .modal-dialog {
        width: 350px;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }
    #modal-img .modal-content {
        width: 350px;
    }
    .cover img.ast-image-lg{
    height: 200px;
    }
}

/* Small devices and tablets */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .header-map{
        display: none;
    }
    .header-text , .header-btns{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .modal-dialog {
        margin: 30px auto;
        width: 350px;
    }
    .modal-content {
        width: 350px;
    }
    #modal-img .modal-dialog {
        margin: 30px auto;
        width: 350px;
    }
    #modal-img .modal-content {
        width: 350px;
    }
    .ast-profile-text>h2{
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size:16px;
    }

    .ast-image-profile
    {
        margin: -45px 10px 0px 25px;
    }
    .cover img.ast-image-lg{ 
        height: 200px;
    }
}
```

The size of image in class ".cover img.ast-image-lg" for medium devices must be 350px and should be 200px for smaller devices .. above classes are working.
I also used meat tag in my header as:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your media queries are both pointing at just 1px away:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px)
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
```

Technically, they should be like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* For Small devices (Tablets) */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
/* For Extra Small devices (Phones) */    
}
```

Please read the docs for reference:
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid